# Problem with Fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

i have written a code like this

```
 public class person
        {
            public person()
            {
                 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
                 public virtual string Code { get; set; }
            } 
        }
        public class Child : Person
        {
            public person()
            {
                 public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
                 public virtual string Lastname{ get; set; }
            } 
        }
        public class Book
       {
           public virtual int Id { get; set; }
           public virtual string Name {get;set;}

       }
```

and my Mapper classes is like these

```
   public class PersonMapping : ClassMap<Person>
   {
            public PersonMapping()
            {
                Table("tblPersons");
                Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
                Map(p => p.Code);

                JoinedSubClass<Child>("Id", MapChild);
            }

            public static void MapChild(JoinedSubClassPart<Child> child)
            {
                child.Table("tblChilds");
                child.Map(p => p.Name);
                child.Map(p => p.Lastname);
                child.HasMany(x => x.Relatives);
              }

    }
    public class RelativeMapping : ClassMap<Relative>
    {

       public RelativeMapping()
       {
          Table("tblRelatives");
          Id(x => x.Id);
          Map(p => p.Name);
          References(x => x.Child).Column("ChildId");
       }


}
```

this is Configuration

```
 Assembly assm = Assembly.Load("BLL");
                return   Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                        .ConnectionString(c => c
                        .FromAppSetting("ConnStr"))
                        .Cache(c => c
                        .UseQueryCache()
                        .ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>())
                        .ShowSql())
                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assm))
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

and this is the code of delete

```
 public void Delete<T>(T obj)
        {
            ISessionFactory fact = FluentConfiguration.CreateSessionFactory();
            ISession session = fact.OpenSession();
            session.Delete(obj);
            session.Flush();

        }
```

my problem : when i wanna delete a Child it messages
" ILLEGAL ATTEMPT TO ASSOCIATE WITH TWO OPEN SESSION "

please help me

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you the problem, and it is not with your entities or your mapping.

You have two or more open sessions and you're attempting to associate some entity with more than one of them.

#### update

In response to the updated code, I see that you have a method that accepts an entity as a parameter, creates a new session factory, creates a new session, and then tries to delete the entity.

There are some problems here:

1. You should only create the session factory once. Ever. This is an expensive operation.
2. You are passing the entity to the `Delete()` method. Where is this entity coming from? You've clearly already loaded it elsewhere in your application, using a different `ISession`. This is the crux of the problem. Unless you `Evict()` the entity from the first `ISession` (not recommended), trying to manipulate it with a different `ISession` will throw.
3. You're calling `Flush()` which should almost never be used.
4. You're using an implicit transaction.

You should really be deleting the entity with the same `ISession` with which it was loaded, and you should be performing work within a transaction, like this:

```
using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Delete(obj);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: hi
thanks for use answer 
but when i wanna add a new child it dosnt have this problem
only in deleting a child it has this problem
what should i do with this?

Comment: @ushuah Potential answerers will need to see the pertinent code in order to assist you -- the code where you are creating session(s) and deleting the child entity.